# How to calculate price with formula?

Tags: price

I want to calculate price with formula: `price = weight*height*width`. How can I do that?

Comment: ...you mean to calculate by volume?

Comment: You can create a local extension where, price will be calculated for each product based on price = weight * height * width;

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but I don't know how to get the value of weight, height, width.

Comment: No, I just want to calculate price by another attribute. Example: price = weight *height * width

Comment: You can create a formula for your product price using this extension - http://www.itoris.com/magento-product-price-formula.html

Answer (score 4):

There are several extensions that will do this for you. You could search on google for `magento calculate price by volume` for example.

If you want to do it yourself you'd have to create a module that observes both `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_update_items_after` and mutate the price based on those attributes.

Below some untested code so you'll have to tweak it but this is basically what should happen.

`/app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    [...]
    <frontend>
        [...]
        <events>
            [...]
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <[namespace]_[module]_checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                        <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkoutCartProductAfter</method>
                    </[namespace]_[module]_checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
                <observers>
                    <[namespace]_[module]_checkout_cart_update_items_after>
                        <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkoutCartUpdateItemsAfter</method>
                    </[namespace]_[module]_checkout_cart_update_items_after>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
            [...]
        </events>
        [...]
    </frontend>
    [...]
</config>
```

and `/app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Observer.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{

    public function checkoutCartProductAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
            $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

            $this->_calculatePrice($item); // here we will set the price

            return $this;
    }

    public function checkoutCartUpdateItemsAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $data = $event->getInfo();
        $quote = $event->getCart()->getQuote();

        foreach ($data as $itemId => $qty) // go through each updated item
        {
            $item = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
            $this->_calculatePrice($item); // here we will set the price
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _calculatePrice(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
    {
        $item = ($item->getParentItem()) ? $item->getParentItem() : $item; // make sure you have the top item

        $basePrice = $item->getPrice();
        $weight = $item->getProduct()->getWeight();
        $height = $item->getProduct()->getHeightAttribute();
        $width = $item->getProduct()->getWidthAttribute();

        $price = $basePrice * $weight * $height * $width;

        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);

        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

}
```